# MVC3 & Bootstrap - Execute function before show Bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I´m newbie in MVC3. I have a button [Generate Password] on my 'Edit' view. I need to execute a function GeneratePsw() defined in 'Admin' controller which returns a string before displaying a modal that will contain the value returned by GeneratePsw().

I also tried to put the value in a ViewBag.pwd instead return it and read it from the Modal. No success

In other words:

The user do click in `[Generate Password]` button. Then `GeneratePsw()` is called and returns a string. A Bootstrap modal should appear automatically displaying that value in a label.

In My View.....

```
<a href="#1" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" data-toggle="modal" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GeneratePsw", "Admin")';return false;"><i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i> Generate Password</a>


</div>


<div id="1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3 id="myModalLabel">Password generated</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
      <p><strong>Password: @(ViewBag.pwd)</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">OK</button>

  </div>
</div>


</td>
```

My GeneratePsw() function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneratePsw()
{

    HomeBridgeEntities ddbb = new HomeBridgeEntities();
    SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)ddbb.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString);
    SupPassGenerator sup = new SupPassGenerator(Cn);

    string psw = sup.CreateRandomPassword(9);

    ViewBag.psw = psw;

    return RedirectToAction("Edit");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my understanding is that you want to do this as an ajax call? i.e. not reload the whole page? I also assume you are using jQuery?

You could do it with a postback to your controller that returns JSON. That might be the easiest way to get it back:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePsw()
{
    ...
    string psw = sup.CreateRandomPassword(9);
    var json = new { password = psw };
    return Json(json);
}
```

js on your page:

```
$('#yourgeneratebutton').on('click', function() {
  $.getJSON('YourController/GeneratePsw', function(data) {
      $('#yourpasswordp').text(data.password);
      $('#1').modal('show');
   });
```

Note, I'm using `getJSON`, so you couldn't decorate the action with `HttpPost`. (You aren't posting any data anyway? You'd either have to change the http attribute, or use `$.post` instead. This is also totally untested, just a rough guide.

OR, an alternative might be to return a partial view that has the modal stuff in it and then show that.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much!! That is exactly what i needed!! Now is working fine thanks to you!